# Login error with Web View - Mercadopago

Tags: angular, nativescript, angular2-nativescript, mercadopago, mercadopagosdk

Im trying to do a simple Mercadopago pay button (basic checkout) with Nativescript. Due a that pay buttom is a html code I have decided put in a WebView to do a simple test. The problem start when I want to pay with mercadopago account because I cant do a login. I try the same process with a browser and I dont have problem.

How can solve this?

To be more precise I made this example.

**WHOLE EXAMPLE IS FOR TEST USER. PLEASE  NOT USE A STANDAR ACCOUNT**

Here is a pay buttom https://ds4fcw2w0otda.cloudfront.net/index_mp.html.If you open with a Browser, you will dont have problem to make a sign in (**Please use test user**).

But if you do the same process with a webview Nativescript-Angular component you be not able to do a sign in.

```js
@Component({
    moduleId: module.id,
    templateUrl: "./mercadopago.component.html",
    styleUrls:["./mercadopago.component.css"]
})

export class MercadopagoComponent{ 
    webview: WebView
    
    public webViewSrc: string = "https://ds4fcw2w0otda.cloudfront.net/index_mp.html";


}
```

```html
<ActionBar title="MERCADOPAGO" automationText="ActionBar">
  <NavigationButton android.systemIcon="ic_menu_back" (tap)="home()" automationText="GoBack"></NavigationButton>    
</ActionBar>
<GridLayout width="100%" rows="0,auto">
  <WebView row="1" [src]="webViewSrc"></WebView>
</GridLayout>
```

NOTE: I suspect that the problem can be something like [this](https://developers.googleblog.com/2016/08/modernizing-oauth-interactions-in-native-apps.html) but I dont know how solve my particular problem

The Log is

**When I load a buttom with a web View**

chromium: [INFO:library_loader_hooks.cc(36)] Chromium logging enabled: level = 0, default verbosity = 0
06-18 00:48:42.466 27226 27226 I cr_BrowserStartup: Initializing chromium process, singleProcess=false

06-18 00:48:42.673 27226 27226 I art     : Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Landroid/webkit/RenderProcessGoneDetail;

06-18 00:48:42.673 27226 27226 I art     :   at void com.android.webview.chromium.WebViewChromium.init(java.util.Map, boolean) (WebViewChromium.java:48)

06-18 00:48:42.673 27226 27226 I art     :   at java.lang.Object com.tns.Runtime.callJSMethodNative(int, int, java.lang.String, int, boolean, java.lang.Object[]) (Runtime.java:-2)

06-18 00:48:42.673 27226 27226 I art     :   at java.lang.Object com.tns.Runtime.dispatchCallJSMethodNative(int, java.lang.String, boolean, long, java.lang.Class, java.lang.Object[]) (Runtime.java:1101)

06-18 00:48:42.673 27226 27226 I art     :   at java.lang.Object com.tns.Runtime.callJSMethodImpl(java.lang.Object, java.lang.String, java.lang.Class, boolean, long, java.lang.Object[]) (Runtime.java:983)

06-18 00:48:42.673 27226 27226 I art     :   at java.lang.Object com.tns.Runtime.callJSMethod(java.lang.Object, java.lang.String, java.lang.Class, boolean, long, java.lang.Object[]) (Runtime.java:970)

06-18 00:48:42.673 27226 27226 I art     :   at java.lang.Object com.tns.Runtime.callJSMethod(java.lang.Object, java.lang.String, java.lang.Class, boolean, java.lang.Object[]) (Runtime.java:954)

06-18 00:48:42.673 27226 27226 I art     :   at java.lang.Object com.tns.Runtime.callJSMethod(java.lang.Object, java.lang.String, java.lang.Class, java.lang.Object[]) (Runtime.java:946)

06-18 00:48:42.673 27226 27226 I art     :   at void com.android.webview.chromium.WebViewChromium.init(java.util.Map, boolean) (WebViewChromium.java:48)

06-18 00:48:42.673 27226 27226 I art     :   at java.lang.Object com.tns.Runtime.callJSMethodNative(int, int, java.lang.String, int, boolean, java.lang.Object[]) (Runtime.java:-2)

06-18 00:48:42.674 27226 27226 I art     :   at java.lang.Object com.tns.Runtime.dispatchCallJSMethodNative(int, java.lang.String, boolean, long, java.lang.Class, java.lang.Object[]) (Runtime.java:1101)

06-18 00:48:42.674 27226 27226 I art     :   at java.lang.Object com.tns.Runtime.callJSMethodImpl(java.lang.Object, java.lang.String, java.lang.Class, boolean, long, java.lang.Object[]) (Runtime.java:983)

06-18 00:48:42.674 27226 27226 I art     :   at java.lang.Object com.tns.Runtime.callJSMethod(java.lang.Object, java.lang.String, java.lang.Class, boolean, long, java.lang.Object[]) (Runtime.java:970)

06-18 00:48:42.674 27226 27226 I art     :   at java.lang.Object com.tns.Runtime.callJSMethod(java.lang.Object, java.lang.String, java.lang.Class, boolean, java.lang.Object[]) (Runtime.java:954)

06-18 00:48:42.674 27226 27226 I art     :   at java.lang.Object com.tns.Runtime.callJSMethod(java.lang.Object, java.lang.String, java.lang.Class, java.lang.Object[]) (Runtime.java:946)

06-18 00:48:42.677 27226 27226 I art     : Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Landroid/webkit/SafeBrowsingResponse;

06-18 00:48:42.677 27226 27226 I art     :   at void com.android.webview.chromium.WebViewChromium.init(java.util.Map, boolean) (WebViewChromium.java:48)

06-18 00:48:42.677 27226 27226 I art     :   at java.lang.Object com.tns.Runtime.callJSMethodNative(int, int, java.lang.String, int, boolean, java.lang.Object[]) (Runtime.java:-2)

06-18 00:48:42.677 27226 27226 I art     :   at java.lang.Object com.tns.Runtime.dispatchCallJSMethodNative(int, java.lang.String, boolean, long, java.lang.Class, java.lang.Object[]) (Runtime.java:1101)

06-18 00:48:42.677 27226 27226 I art     :   at java.lang.Object com.tns.Runtime.callJSMethodImpl(java.lang.Object, java.lang.String, java.lang.Class, boolean, long, java.lang.Object[]) (Runtime.java:983)

06-18 00:48:42.677 27226 27226 I art     :   at java.lang.Object com.tns.Runtime.callJSMethod(java.lang.Object, java.lang.String, java.lang.Class, boolean, long, java.lang.Object[]) (Runtime.java:970)

06-18 00:48:42.677 27226 27226 I art     :   at java.lang.Object com.tns.Runtime.callJSMethod(java.lang.Object, java.lang.String, java.lang.Class, boolean, java.lang.Object[]) (Runtime.java:954)

06-18 00:48:42.677 27226 27226 I art     :   at java.lang.Object com.tns.Runtime.callJSMethod(java.lang.Object, java.lang.String, java.lang.Class, java.lang.Object[]) (Runtime.java:946)

06-18 00:48:42.677 27226 27226 I art     :   at void com.android.webview.chromium.WebViewChromium.init(java.util.Map, boolean) (WebViewChromium.java:48)

06-18 00:48:42.677 27226 27226 I art     :   at java.lang.Object com.tns.Runtime.callJSMethodNative(int, int, java.lang.String, int, boolean, java.lang.Object[]) (Runtime.java:-2)

06-18 00:48:42.677 27226 27226 I art     :   at java.lang.Object com.tns.Runtime.dispatchCallJSMethodNative(int, java.lang.String, boolean, long, java.lang.Class, java.lang.Object[]) (Runtime.java:1101)

06-18 00:48:42.677 27226 27226 I art     :   at java.lang.Object com.tns.Runtime.callJSMethodImpl(java.lang.Object, java.lang.String, java.lang.Class, boolean, long, java.lang.Object[]) (Runtime.java:983)

06-18 00:48:42.677 27226 27226 I art     :   at java.lang.Object com.tns.Runtime.callJSMethod(java.lang.Object, java.lang.String, java.lang.Class, boolean, long, java.lang.Object[]) (Runtime.java:970)

06-18 00:48:42.677 27226 27226 I art     :   at java.lang.Object com.tns.Runtime.callJSMethod(java.lang.Object, java.lang.String, java.lang.Class, boolean, java.lang.Object[]) (Runtime.java:954)

06-18 00:48:42.677 27226 27226 I art     :   at java.lang.Object com.tns.Runtime.callJSMethod(java.lang.Object, java.lang.String, java.lang.Class, java.lang.Object[]) (Runtime.java:946)

**When I press "Pagar" buttom**

chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(0)] "The SSL certificate used to load resources from https://data.mercadolibre.com will be distrusted in the future. Once distrusted, users will be prevented from loading these resources. See https://g.co/chrome/symantecpkicerts for more information.", source: https://www.mercadopago.com.ar/cuotas?seller_id=269515452&marketplace=NONE&iframe=true (0)

**When I fill an user name**

chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(6)] "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'toString' of undefined", source: https://www.mercadopago.com/mla/checkout/pay?pref_id=269515452-257c5142-68a0-4bb7-ac9f-d1eac5883ee3&flowId=472d573f-569e-4168-9947-f33642372dcd&logout=true (6)

**But I cant catch nothing when I do a login. Only I catch some log with webview.on() method. If I submit to a Start Load Event and a Finish Load Event the log is**

chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(6)] "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'toString' of undefined", source: https://www.mercadopago.com/mla/checkout/pay?pref_id=269515452-257c5142-68a0-4bb7-ac9f-d1eac5883ee3&flowId=472d573f-569e-4168-9947-f33642372dcd&logout=true (6)

JS: WebView loadStartedEvent- WebView started loading of https://www.mercadolibre.com/jms/mla/lgz/login/authenticate

JS: WebView loadStartedEvent- WebView started loading of https://www.mercadopago.com/mla/checkout/pay?execution=e7s1&_eventId=next&errors.invalid_attempts=6&errors.user=email_not_found&errors.user_id=not_found&platform_id=mp&site_id=mla&go=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.mercadopago.com%2Fmla%2Fcheckout%2Fpay%3Fexecution%3De7s1%26_eventId%3Dnext&user_id=test_user_1038255%40testuser.com&remember_me=true&loginType=DEFAULT&registered=true

JS: WebView loadFinishedEvent - WebView finish loading of https://www.mercadopago.com/mla/checkout/pay?execution=e7s1&_eventId=next&errors.invalid_attempts=6&errors.user=email_not_found&errors.user_id=not_found&platform_id=mp&site_id=mla&go=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.mercadopago.com%2Fmla%2Fcheckout%2Fpay%3Fexecution%3De7s1%26_eventId%3Dnext&user_id=test_user_1038255%40testuser.com&remember_me=true&loginType=DEFAULT&registered=true#login

JS: WebView loadFinishedEvent - WebView finish loading of https://www.mercadopago.com/mla/checkout/pay?execution=e7s1&_eventId=next&errors.invalid_attempts=6&errors.user=email_not_found&errors.user_id=not_found&platform_id=mp&site_id=mla&go=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.mercadopago.com%2Fmla%2Fcheckout%2Fpay%3Fexecution%3De7s1%26_eventId%3Dnext&user_id=test_user_1038255%40testuser.com&remember_me=true&loginType=DEFAULT&registered=true#login

Comment: did you tried outputing webview error to console ?

Comment: Thanks for your interest! I added a log

Comment: `Cannot read property 'toString'` could be the case. You need to inspect webview. If you are on Mac, you can use safari inspector on device or simulator and similarly on windows you can use chrome inspect

Comment: I have tryed do inspect webview but I havent be able activate debbuging. I tryed with **webView.android.setWebContentsDebuggingEnabled(true);** but appear an error where say setWebContentsDebuggingEnabled is not a function. Then I had install **npm  tns-platform-declarations** to use API native and try with **android.webkit.WebView.setWebContentsDebuggingEnabled(true);** but nothing. Another thing that I tryed is modify **minSdkVersion** from manifiest.xml I setted in 19 (API in which was added setWebContentsDebuggingEnabled)